# Uncaught TypeError: b.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am getting an uncaught type error in ajax file in console, even though everything is working properly...

the html is

```
<div id="deletepropertybutton"><a href = "editproperty.php?property_id=<?php echo $data['property_id'];?>" class="editpropertybutton">Edit</a></div>
```

the php is

```
$del_id = ($_POST['del_id']);

$delete = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_property WHERE property_id='$del_id'");
$delete->execute();

$delete2 = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_favorite_properties WHERE favorite_properties_property_id='$del_id'");
$delete2->execute();
```

and ajax is

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.deletepropertybutton').click(function()
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../controllers/deleteproperty.php',
            data:
            {
                del_id: del_id
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "../controllers/managepropertiesajax.php",
                    success: function(data3)
                    {
                        $('#propertycounter').html("(" + data3 + ")");
                    }
                });
                $ele.fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).remove(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

how should i go about fixing this kind of error.. i am having this in other ajax files also the full error code is

Uncaught TypeError: b.replace is not a function

```
at Function.ga.matchesSelector (jquery.js:2)
at Function.r.filter (jquery.js:2)
at Ia (jquery.js:3)
at r.fn.init.remove (jquery.js:3)
at Object.success (deletepropertyajax.js:27)
at i (jquery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
at A (jquery.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:4)
```

Comment: Where is the variable `b`? Where is the `.replace()` happening?

Comment: there is no variable b, it is coming in jquery file... which i have downloaded from jquery site

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Please take a look at your title, and check if it is valid.

Comment: please see edit, i have pasted the full error there (copy and paste from console)

Comment: apparently $ele.fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).remove(1000); this is causing it removing this removes the error

Comment: please use the `ctrl + F` feature to check the entire project (Even the built files) to find `b.replace()`. Also, which file causes the error.

Comment: `b.replace` is internall (probably in jQuery's code) so you probably missuse something (passing the wrong type as parametter)!

Comment: what is the output of `console.log('$ele') `? after assignment to var $ele

Comment: yes b.replace is in jquery internal code that is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the docs to [`jQuery.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

In the docs it sais that `remove` expects an optional parameter which is a selector. Since you are calling it with a delay `1000` (number), jQuery excpects a selector (string) which is causing the problem (numbers don't have a function called `replace`).

Remove the parameter of `remove` like this:

```
$ele.fadeOut(1000)
    .delay(1000)
    .remove();     // no parameter for remove
```

If you want to keep the fadeout effect use the callback (second optional parameter to `fadeout`) like this:

```
$ele.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $ele.remove();
});
```

Comment: yes this fixes it but it also removes the fade out effect

Comment: these downvoter just downvote without explanation... stackoverflow should reveal their identity and force them to give reason

Comment: i have upvoted your answer ibrahim thanks for helping

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I want to know how this is different from what OP had in his code?

Comment: @DragonFire Check the update answer it handles what you want!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I think you got downvoted because you mentioned **Try this** against what OP had in his code.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal If you read my answer you'll see that it solves the problem, which is (if you want me to say it here in the comment), passing a number to `remove` which expects a string not a number, and since numbers don't have `replace` function defined for them (which jQuery is using internally on the selector) this cause the problem!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I read your answer before the update, where only the method chain was newline-separated and hence my doubt. Your edited answer is right. Sadly I have no upvotes left for the day so I can't upvote.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal If the downvoter just read the comment without reading the explanation he would've find out that the changes are not just the newlines. SO should really force downvoters to leave a comment so we can have an argument about they're decisions. Downvoting alone won't do any good especially if the poster doesn't know where he made a mistake.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir that is true, I would strongly recommend editing your answer and removing the 'Try this' text. You can also approach SO moderators to have your case reviewed.

Comment: peace guys.  i am thankful for all of you for taking interest in my question and answering... i am upvoting everyone in the name of peace

Comment: @DragonFire I'm peacefully leaving this page!

Comment: @DragonFire You're welcome! Glad to help! One thing I've just noticed, you can get rid of `delay`. See the update of the function!

Comment: @DragonFire Just remove the element after the fadeout is complete as I don't think it's necessary to wait 1 second (the item is already invisible) and use `$ele` as `$(this)` is redundant!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  yes even this is working :  $ele.fadeOut(1000);

Comment: @DragonFire but the element is just hidden (`display: none`) not removed from the DOM! If you want to remove it at all from the DOM use my code!